# Salesforce Data Loader OAuth not taking another email address

Tags: data-loader, oauth, data-export

I am trying to log in to a production environment in Data Loader through OAuth and giving a custom domain, then it is taking my personal outlook account and directly giving an error without giving option to remove the old one and adding new (work) email address that I want to use. It gives error `AADSTS50177: User account 'personal.email@outlook.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant`

[image: screen shot with the error]

Comment: I think the root cause might be cache memory. Try clearing the browser's recent history, cookies and cache memory and login again. Also, you could try using the Chrome's Incognito version.

Comment: I got that fixed, I ran a cleanup using a software, clearing the cookies, caches etc.

Comment: Glad my comment helped. Do you want me to write the same comment as an answer, so that you could mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Data Loader app (version 46), File menu > Logout. Nothing visible happens but don't let that fool you - your current session on the Data Loader side will be terminated and it will "forget" the credentials you used to sign in.